# websocket, socket,io, sockjs, meteor...confused about how to make choices TODAY

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, real-time, sockjs

I am about to make a decision for a collaborative editing application. I investigated about websockets, and frankly I am confused. Here my findings so far:

- There are loads of articles about websockets - but many are dated 2009, 2010...Often there's info that websockets are not fully functional in all browsers and/or that implementations are crappy...What's the status today?
- There are plenty of frameworks around - but mostly for node. Our application is in RoR, and Eventmachine/em-websocket looks like a year old - will it still be up for today's requirements?
- Socket.io, SockJS, meteor...there are so many and I won't be able to try them all, but I did some first trials with SockJS. Our app is collaborative editing of binary data; multiple users might be editing the same document, and multiple users may be working on different documents at the same time. Thus, scalability is key; SockJS seems not to scale over more than one server (sticky sessions). Also, clients would need updates from peers - do I need broadcasting facility? Would I need redis for this?

I guess my questions then boil down to this:

- For our app, should I use websockets directly and customize or use a
  framework?
- If a framework, which one is recommended more for our specific needs?

I know these questions are a bit vague but I really first of all would like to get an up-to-date understanding of where technology is to make some sound decisions. 
Thank you!

Comment: For scalability nothing beats short polling. The Web is highly optimised for GET. Control the poll interval from the server by using cache expiration. Live connections are sexy, but moving off a single server becomes interesting. Sorry to answer in a comment, closing interesting questions seems to be a trademark fail of the SO community.